# julia: How to grab a portion of an array

Tags: arrays, julia

What is the most efficient (Julia) way to grab the a portion of an array? Keeping in mind that Julia index starts at 1 not 0

```
>>> myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> #from an index to the last index?
>>> myArray[4th to last]
[4,5,6,7,8]
>>> #from an index to another index?
>>> myArray[3rd to 5th]
[3,4,5]
```

Comment: Do you want the output to be independent of the original array (ie operations on the output do not affect the original array) or is a view into the original array sufficient? In the first case, just use `myArray[x:y]` since a slice (in v0.4) creates a copy of the original. In the second case, use `sub(myArray, x:y)`, and the output is a sub-array (no copy operation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

start at 1

myArray[4:end]

myArray[3:5]

http://samuelcolvin.github.io/JuliaByExample/

http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/